# Issue building synapse 2.1.0-wso2v6 - java-cup:pom:0.0

Tags: wso2

I'm running into an issue building synapse 2.1.0-wso2v6 from the platform branch 4.0.0:

```
C:\wso2\src\wso2carbon_platform_branch_400\dependencies\synapse\2.1.0-wso2v6\modules\commons>mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

The error log:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Synapse - Commons classes 2.1.0-wso2v6
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/java-cup/java-cup/0.0/java-cup-0.0.pom
Downloading: https://server.oosnmp.net/dist/release/java-cup/java-cup/0.0/java-cup-0.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/java-cup/java-cup/0.0/java-cup-0.0.pom
Downloading: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/JLex/JLex/0.0/JLex-0.0.pom
Downloading: https://server.oosnmp.net/dist/release/JLex/JLex/0.0/JLex-0.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/JLex/JLex/0.0/JLex-0.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.361s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 04 15:55:04 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/490M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project synapse-commons: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.synapse:synapse-commons:bundle:2.1.0-wso2v6: ...
...
Could not transfer artifact java-cup:java-cup:pom:0.0 from/to snmp4j-repo (https://server.oosnmp.net/dist/release/): hostname in certificate didn't match: <server.oosnmp.net> != <oosnmp.net> OR <oosnmp.net> -> [Help 1]
```

Basically, it seems that java-cup pom can't be found.

Here are the steps I followed leading up to the failure:

```
wso2\src\wso2carbon_orbit_branch_400>mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
wso2\src\wso2carbon_orbit_branch_400\patch-releases\4.0.6>mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

wso2\src\wso2carbon_kernel_branch_400>mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true 
wso2\src\wso2carbon_kernel_branch_400\patch-releases\4.0.6>mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true 

wso2\src\wso2carbon_platform_branch_400>mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true 
>> java-cup maven failure
```

Comment: The steps you mentioned are correct. I tried to build synapse\2.1.0-wso2v6\modules\commons this works fine on me. Please try to build it again after taking svn update on the component.

Comment: @Manoj - Same problem after svn update.  I think I will try and do a fresh checkout and build on a new virtual machine in case my maven repo has got corrupt on my development machine.

Comment: @Manoj - I commented out the oosnmp repository, performed a `rm -rf` of 2.1.0-wso2v6, and then a `svn update`.  Synapse is now building fine.  Many thanks!

Comment: Great. Hope you resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing following repository from the synapse root pom (C:\wso2\src\wso2carbon_platform_branch_400\dependencies\synapse\2.1.0-wso2v6\pom.xml).

```
    <repository>
        <id>snmp4j-repo</id>
        <name>SNMP4J Repository</name>
        <url>https://server.oosnmp.net/dist/release/</url>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Comment: Thanks, that has got me a bit further.  However, I now have compile errors related to java-cups, e.g. `SynapseMOScalar.java:[37,45] type org.snmp4j.agent.mo.MOScalar does not take parameters`

Comment: 2.1.0-wso2v7 was able to build it ok after commenting out the snmp4j-repo.  Hopefully I should be able to work it out from here.  Many thanks.